# Jquery Datepicker input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I add input fields with the same "id" dynamically. But when I focus on input field and select date from datepicker, this value update on first input field element. How can I update value on target input field?

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/me3jt4qc/)`is here`

Comment: The Id attribute must be unique. You may want to bind using a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... you want to bind using class.

```js
$(function(){  
   $(document).on('focus', '.datepick', function () { 
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
    });    
    
});
```

```css
.fields {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'fields'>
<input id="field1" type="text" class="datepick"/>
</div>
<div class = 'fields'>
<input id="field2" type="text" class="datepick"/>
</div>
<div class = 'fields'>
<input id="field3" type="text" class="datepick"/>
</div>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of errors in your HTML. You can't assign an  `id`  to more than one element.

I have edited your HTML and Jquery.

See working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bgx57z92/).